# ESLint: Error: Failed to load config "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat" to extend from

Tags: angular, npm

I have tried updating an Angular project from version 15 to 16, now I get several errors that I can't make sense of. IntelliJ shows the following error at the top:

[image]

I don't know if it's related, but running ng serve also fails with many module errors where I can't really see what's wrong. Mostly it says

```
NG6002: This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule.
```

[image]

does anyone have a suggestion how to fix that?

Answer (score 18):

I just removed the references to the below plugins in **.eslint.jso**n under **extends** section

```
"plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
"plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
```

and added the below

```
"plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended"
```

The **extends** now looks as below

```
"extends": [
   "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
   "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
],
```

Answer (score 6):

`ng-cli-compat` was removed you have to follow instructions here: https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/1353#issuecomment-1529924573